# iPhone doesn't show up using Adobe Animate CC

Tags: iphone, air, flash-cc, animate-cc

Hey everyone so I have an iPhone 4(I know old) and I am trying to publish my app using Adobe Air for IOS 26.0. My computer and iTunes recognizes the apple device perfectly but when I try to publish it in Animate where it says "Install application on connected IOS device" mine doesn't show up at all. I tried restarting the device and computer and tried multiple USB cables as well. Nothing is working. Please any help is appreciated.

Comment: Upgrade to the latest Air 27.

Answer (score 1):

Updating AIR won't fix this as the process of detecting a device is through Animate, not AIR. I can confirm Animate can still detect iPhone 4. Mine is running iOS 7.1.2

Try connecting in this order:

1. Launch Animate
2. Unlock your iPhone
3. Connect your iPhone via USB
4. Debug Menu > Debug Movie > On Device via USB > Refresh Device List

Comment: Author didn't mentioned, but I'm pretty sure that it's Windows - iOS connection problem after iTunes' update, so Air SDK upgrade is mandatory
https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2387478

Comment: Hey guys I managed to fix it. It was due to the new iTunes update. I believe Adobe is working on the fix for the new update 12.7. I had to remove iTunes and Download a older version 12.5.1 and it works now.

Comment: @Nathan, had the same problem, but instead of downgrading iTunes, updating Air SDK helped in my case.